# How to enable server side encryption for multiple S3 buckets using AWS CLI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, aws-cli

I have around 100 S3 buckets and I want to enable SSE-Encryption for these buckets using AWS CLI.
I've gone through some AWS docs for this. Seems like I can use the below command:

aws s3api put-bucket-encryption 
--bucket my-bucket 
--server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'

But I want to exclude a few buckets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You say you're running on Linux, so you can use a shell loop.

First, store the list of buckets in a file (the `sed` command is necessary because the `aws s3 ls` adds timestamp information to the output):

```
aws s3 ls | sed -e 's/.* //' > /tmp/$$
```

Then, edit this file and delete any buckets that you don't want to update.

Finally, run your command in a loop:

```
for b in $(cat /tmp/$$) ; do YOUR_COMMAND_HERE ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

In general this should be done carefully because it will affect all buckets except the excluded

Make sure you know what you're doing.

```
#!/bin/bash

# excluded buckets list
excluded_list="my-excluded-bucket-1|my-excluded-bucket-2|my-excluded-bucket-3"

aws s3 ls | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -vE "$excluded_list"

echo "#############################################################"
echo "# WARNING: The above s3 buckets encryption will be updated. #"
echo "#############################################################"

read -p "Continue (y/n)?" choice
case "$choice" in 
  y|Y ) echo "yes";;
  n|N ) echo "no";exit;;
  * ) echo "invalid";exit;;
esac

for b in $(aws s3 ls | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -vE "$excluded_list"); do
    aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket $b --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
done
```